# Http proxy server tests

Tags: proxy, server, load-testing, stress-testing, http-proxy

I have implemented a http proxy client/server. Currently I intended to test this proxy client/server performance. Can anybody help me what approaches exists to make these tests?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for, Ehsan? What sort of tests are you trying to do? Are you asking about the theory of stress-testing, or any particular tools...?

Comment: I'm intended to test proxy server load test. I want to know how many concurrent users the server can load. (thank u so much)

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to better explain what exactly you're trying to achieve. It has been "put on hold" because your question is currently too broad. Please read the note right below your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for some tools the following will be helpful for you:

**RoboHydra** is a web server designed precisely to help you write and test software that uses HTTP as a communication protocol. There are many ways to use

1. RoboHydra, but the most common use cases are as follows: RoboHydra
   allows you to combine a locally stored website front end with a back
   end sat on a remote server, allowing you to test your own local
   front end installation with a fully functional back end, without
   having to install the back end on your local machine.
2. If you write a program designed to talk to a server using HTTP, you
   can use RoboHydra to imitate that server and pass custom responses
   to the program. This can help you reproduce different bugs and
   situations that might be otherwise hard, if not impossible, to test.

https://dev.opera.com/articles/robohydra-testing-client-server-interactions/

**Webserver Stress Tool** simulates large numbers of users accessing a website via HTTP/HTTPS. The software can simulate up to 10.000 users that independently click their way through a set of URLs. Simple URL patterns are supported as well as complex URL patterns (via a Script file).

Webserver Stress Tool supports a number of different testing types. For example

✓ Performance Tests—this test queries single URLs of a webserver or web application to identify and discover elements that may be responsible for slower than expected performance. This test provides a unique opportunity to optimize server settings or application configurations by testing various implementations of single web pages/script to identify the fastest code or settings.

✓ Load Tests—this tests your entire website at the normal (expected) load. For load testing you simply enter the URLs, the number of users, and the time between clicks of your website traffic. This is a “real world” test.

✓ Stress Tests—these are simulations of “brute force” attacks that apply excessive load to your webserver. This type of “brute force” situation can be caused by a massive spike in user activity (i.e., a new advertising campaign). This is a great test to find the traffic threshold for your webserver.

✓ Ramp Tests—this test uses escalating numbers of users over a given time frame to determine the maximum number of users the webserver can accommodate before producing error messages.

✓ Various other tests—working with Webserver Stress Tool simply gives you more insight about your website, e.g. to determine that web pages can be requested simultaneously without problems like database deadlocks, semaphores, etc.

http://www.paessler.com/tools/webstress/features

To better understand what is client-server and web based testing and how to test these applications you may read this post http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/what-is-client-server-and-web-based-testing-and-how-to-test-these-applications/